# TFS 2015 Upgrade to Azure DevOps Question: Is there an upgrade wizard?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I have a question in regards to upgrading TFS to Azure DevOps 2020.  I've not done anything like this before so I've started reading BOL, starting here, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/upgrade/get-started?view=azure-devops-2020, but I still have some questions.

**From Setup:**

- On-premises TFS 2015 - SQL Server 2016

**Going to Setup:**

- On-premises Azure DevOps 2020 (new hardware) - SQL Server 2019

**Plan:**

1. Install SQL 2019 on new server
2. Restore TFS DB backups on new SQL 2019 server
3. Install Azure Dev Ops 2020 software on the new server

**Questions:**

1. Is there a TFS Upgrade wizard?
2. If so, at this point in the plan, should I run the TFS upgrade wizard?
3. If so, where do I run it from, the old server (as TFS isn't installed on the new server)?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The recommended approach to doing these upgrades is to stand up a test environment and walk through the upgrade process before you do it for real. That would answer most of your questions.

Comment: Hi @JM1, Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now? Any update for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes. TFS Upgrade wizard is a general tool.
2. After restoring databases and installing new azure devops server.
3. On the new application server.

Check [inplace upgrade](https://oshamrai.wordpress.com/2021/01/18/upgrade-azure-devops-server-to-2020/) to 2020.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Shamrai Aleksander.

You could refer to the blog to upgrade the Azure DevOps Server. Then we could use [data migration tool](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/devops/migrate/) to [migrate data from Azure DevOps Server to Azure DevOps Services.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/migrate/migration-overview?view=azure-devops)

The data migration tool for Azure DevOps supports the two latest releases of Azure DevOps Server at a given time. Releases include updates and major releases. Currently the following versions of Azure DevOps Server are supported for import:

1. Azure DevOps Server 2020
2. Azure DevOps Server 2019.1.1

In addition, check this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/upgrade/run-upgrade-wizard?view=azure-devops-2020), It also show the detail steps to run TFS Upgrade Wizard.